# Video Streaming Server on Mobile

Tags: java, mobile, symbian, s60, rtsp

I have seen video streaming to mobile phones. I would like to know whether we have a streaming server that can be installed on mobile phone and stream video to another device from the camera present on the phone. I would like to have on for my Nokia N70 phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QIK](http://qik.com/) does something like that.  They support a lot of Nokia phones, but unfortunately it looks like the N70 isn't among them.  Probably not useful if you're looking to build your own application, but at least it shows that it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but due to processor limitations (often a 200-600MHz 32 bit ARM or similar) mobile phones can't compress high resolution video in realtime.  Further, the bandwidth is very low, even with high speed 3G connections.

These two limitations mean that you can likely find CIF resolution, and occasionally slow frame rate VGA resolution streaming, but it's non trivial to get anything better than that.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

Device to device would be tough -- however, if you used an intermediary, you might have better luck.  Something like Qik to broadcast from the device to your website, then have the 2nd device connect to that stream -- similar to how Quicktime Broadcaster (not mobile related) sends its single stream to the streaming server, which then handles the distribution.

Like Adam mentions above, I would not expect high quality.   Even over 3g, 10fps+ and QCIF+ video can be rather unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Seen [bambuser](http://bambuser.com/node/70403)? A video streaming service that can stream live from mobiles and webcams.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few service

1. [Qik](http://qik.com)
2. [Kyte.tv](http://kyte.tv)
3. Ustream